# Drupal - Tag a user with own username

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to work out the best way to add a node's author to a list specific to the current user, which could be used create a 'favourite user' list for example.

I'm not sure about the best approach here... one idea I have in mind is to tag the node's author with the current user's username somehow, and then filter a user list with Views...

So I guess my actual question is '**Can you tag a user/user profile with the current user's username?**'

This functionality would be useful for several networking things I have in mind!

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

Try that [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module.

Add arbitrary flag to be displayed on node/profile. Add custom rules OR hook_flag.

Done.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll give it a go. Cheers.